# Enumerating over an array but passing a subset of the array to the block instead of a single element

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby, and I have been reading a lot of tutorials.  Yesterday I SWEAR I read an example of the `each` statement (or something like it) that enumerated over an array, and then passed a subset of the array to the block.  Here's an example, but the syntax is wrong (or I am using the wrong method) so this will not actually run.

```
arry = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

arry.each(3) {|a, b, c| puts a+b+c}
```

If I was using the right command, this would print:`abc bcd cde`; it takes the first three members of the array starting at the index and the enumeration ends when there isn't a string long enough to provide all three arguments.  I can't remember how to do it and I can't seem to google the right thing to find it.  Do any of you guys know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`each_cons(3)` behaves like that. It is in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) (Array includes Enumerable), that's why you couldn't find it.

Comment: Arg!!!  I read the whole Array section on ruby-doc, and then I saw that it was a child of Object so I check Object just to be sure.  I totally missed that it included the Enumerables module.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like `combination` ?

```
arry.combination(3).each {|a, b, c| p a+b+c}
```

Comment: This was not quite what I was looking for, but very close.

Coincedentally, a problem I was working on later needed `combination` so thank you for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about `each_slice`?

```
arry.each_slice(3) {|a,b,c| p a+b+c}
```

Comment: each slice would do a,b,c then c,d,nil not a,b,c ; b,c,d etc. as the OP wanted